# Not enough rep to upvote?

Tags: bug, ios-app

I have plenty of rep to upvote and comment everywhere but when I try to upvote an answer I get an error message saying that because I have less than 15 rep points my vote doesn't count publicly.  What gives?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 11.4.1 (Build 15G77)

Edit: Does rep not carry over between sub-sites? Like, if I have rep on Network Engineering, it doesn't mean I have rep on Ask Different (Apple)?

Comment: Just because you know a lot about Network Engineering doesn't mean you know anything about Apple.

Comment: @patricksweeney That’s fair. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. The association bonus is so that if you DO have previous experience on other SE sites, that a certain level of know-how and civility can be assumed that you will be a "good citizen" on any other site; so that bonus is meant as a slight bump to get you over the "basic" requirements for things that are "locked" at low reputations.

Comment: @patricksweeney Thanks. That makes sense. I guess I’ll just have to work my way up to that 200+ mark.

Comment: @Glorfindel It is partially a duplicate however that document doesn't actually say that you don't get ANY rep shared without first having 200+ on a linked account - just that you get 100 on all sites if you do.  Maybe I'm reading too much into it but it is a technicality.

Comment: Well, it does say "All users start with one reputation point."

Comment: @Glorfindel Sure, but it doesn't state that you get NO rep association unless you have hit 200+ somewhere. The word "bonus" implies that there is already an association of rep but that you get an ADDITIONAL boost if you reach 200+ somewhere. Again, I could be reading too much into it but if you take the doc literally, what I said seems valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug, you just don't yet have enough rep to earn the association bonus (as noted in comments). We're *considering* a feature that would let a user that has upvote privileges on at least one other site *queue* their votes on a new site, which would get applied as soon as they have enough rep to vote, but there are some challenges there.

A lot of other user research also points at us needing something better than our current anon feedback mechanism for folks to say "thanks", so we're looking into that too.

We've resisted doing more here because of complexity and increased surface for shenanigans in the past, but the demand for better ways to just say "thanks" has gone up considerably since we've grown and saturated search engines so well, so we're talking about it.

No timeline yet, but it's on the radar.